# Running an MSPL script in UCMA Application ServerAgent.WaitForServerAvailable Error

Tags: c#, skype, lync, ucma

I have a Skype for Business Server 2015 environment with an Edge Server, Front End Server and Trusted Application server. (All as separate servers)

I have a TrustedApplication Endpoint that I want to publish it's presence to PIC Clients which needs an MSPL and UCMA application to get the presence and reply to the external Skype Clients.  I have followed the microsoft Tutorial at [Extending Unified Communications Services of UCMA Bots to PIC Clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj128288(v=office.14).)
However I cannot get this application to Successfully load the MSPL script in the UCMA application. I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Error on the ServerAgent.WaitForServerAvailable(3) Line when running this on the Trusted Application server.

From extended reading on this issue, In order to get MSPL to Work it needs to be on the Front End Server and the UCMA Application cannot run on the Front End server. However both of these in the example are part of the same Application (in order for the Dispatch to Raise the event back to the UCMA application). So I'm confused as to how this example actually should work.

I can Run the MSPL part of the Tutorial App without the UCMA component onj the front end server and can see the Dispatch being Called. I can Run the UCMA component on the TruestedApplication Server and see the endpoint Establish but can't get both together?

Is there something I am missing with my Topology setup or has something changed in Sfb2015?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MSPL scripts can only run on FrontEnd servers. You should extract it from UCMA application itself because Trusted Application server doesn't get incoming or outgoing requests. Also FrontEnd server cannot proceed UCMA application.

Your MSPL application can be a windows service or console application that runs on frontend server.

Because UCMA application sends/gets requests from FrontEnd server itself and MSPL scripts gets/sets these requests as you wish. If you do not interrupt it goes on as it is.

See below link:
http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/07/26/installing-troubleshooting-mspl-scripts/

Comment: Thanks for the Help @Kadir. 
I can run a UCMA application on the front end server. Interestingly in the Shell scripts in the tutorial they actually do configure the Front End server as a Trusted Application server. However this still does't seem to fix the issue. 

I have been able to get the application to run on the front end server however now I am getting a A481 error when sending the SIP response, which i will need to ask another stack question for.